Using the enhanced ccp1 in pic18f does not output PWM
I was implementing a driver for ccp1 peripheral and after implementing it and using proteus for simulation, the enhanced PWM doesn't work while I made sure that the CCP1CON is loaded correctly and T2CON too and I don't know what is the problem.
It should output 50% duty cycle with 20kHz with P1A, P1C both active low and P1B, P1D both active high.
And according to datasheet Full-bridge output forward, P1D modulated; P1A active; P1B, P1C inactive.
Here are the registers of CCP1CON and T2CON and also TRISC and TRISD:
registers value
output config
The code:
#include "app.h"
#include "device_config.h"
#include "MCAL_Layer/CCPx/CCP1/hal_ccp1.h"
#include "MCAL_Layer/Timers/Timer3/hal_timer3.h"
#include "MCAL_Layer/Timers/Timer2/hal_timer2.h"

cpp1_t ccp1_obj = {
  .ccp1_interrupt_handler = NULL,
  .ccp1_interrupt_priority = INTERRUPT_LOW_PRIORITY,
  .ccp1_mode = CCP1_PWM_MODE_SELECT,
  .ccp1_mode_variant = CCP1_PWM_MODE_P1AC_LOW_P1BD_HIGH,
  .ccp1_pwm_output_config = FULL_BRIDGE_OUTPUT_FORWARD,
  .ccp1_pwm_frequency = 20000,
  .timer2_postscaler_value = 1,
  .timer2_prescaler_value = 1
};
timer2_t timer2_obj = {
  .PR2_preloaded_value = 99,
  .TMR2_preloaded_value = 0,
  .postscaler_value = 1,
  .prescaler_value = 1
};
int main(void)
{
    Std_ReturnType ret = E_OK;
    ret |= ccp1_init(&ccp1_obj);
    ret |= timer2_init(&timer2_obj);
    ccp1_pwm_set_duty_cycle(50);
    while (1)
    {

    }
    return (ret);
}

I don't know what to do after that and it doesn't output PWM.

What are the return values of the functions you are calling? Do they return error codes?

@mkrieger1 no only the ccp1_init as the interrupt handler is the stuct is null(it means that this object cant use interrupts because of that and it isn't necessarily needed in pwm mode)

Which PIC18 are you using? Have you switched your ouüut pins to digital? Is Timer 2 running?

@Mike I am using pic18f4620 and yeah the pins of the CCP1 are all digitals and they are output

And is Timer2 running? Please check

@Mike Yeah sorry i forgot to add it to the screenshot in this question but T2CON value is 00000100 which means prescaler and postscaler are 1:1 and TMR2ON is 1

You had to switch your ports to digital with ADCON1register. Where did you do this?

@Mike it only changes AN0 to AN12 pins to digital but P1A, P1B, P1C and P1D are multiplexed on different pins from any ANx pins
